# Load image when i scroll

Tags: jquery, scroll, gif

I use this for displaying gif when i scroll :

```
<img class="gif-load1" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/nos-services-title.gif" data-small="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/white-service.jpg" />


<script type="text/javascript">             
var largeImage = $('.gif-load1').attr('src');
            var smallImage = $('.gif-load1').attr('data-small');

            $(window).bind('scroll', function() {
                if ($(window).scrollTop() > 300) {
                    $('.gif-load1').attr('src', smallImage);

                } else {
                    $('.gif-load1').attr('src', largeImage);

                }
            });
</script>
```

I have a problem when i scroll, the gif display/hide/display/hide

I don't know why. :(

This is the website : http://www.groupensci.com/agencen/

Lost. Please need help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should you not test if the picture is already loaded?

It is just a guess but from what I read, "Scroll" is fired every time a scroll occurs. Not just from someone starts the scrolling or finishes scrolling.

So you ask the browser to fetch an image all the time as I understand it. I would add, to test, this to see if it makes a difference:

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
                if ($(window).scrollTop() > 300) {
                  if($('.gif-load1').attr('src')!=smallImage) 
                    $('.gif-load1').attr('src', smallImage);
                } else {
                   if($('.gif-load1').attr('src')!=largeImage)
                    $('.gif-load1').attr('src', largeImage);

                }
            });
```

Comment: Like a boss vm2013, Thank you so much! It's really perfect. =D